# How to remove metadata from rmarkdown rendered documents?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a RMarkdown document that I'm rendering as a word document using a template as reference.

This is the code:

````
---
output:
  word_document:
  pandoc_args: [
  "--reference-doc=template_report.docx"
]
 always_allow_html: no
 ---

#Report starts here

```{r setup, include=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(pander)
library(rmarkdown)
library(webshot)

#Some code
```
````

The issue is that the word document has the same metadata printed in the report which I don't want.

```
output:
word_document:
pandoc_args: [
“–reference-doc=template_exec_report.docx”
]
always_allow_html: yes

Report starts here
```

Is there a way to remove this?

Could this because of change in R-versions. We recently moved to RStudio cloud environment and there might be a change in R-version.

Edit: This is occurring this in R 4.0.5. It is working fine in R 3.5.0